# Implement error handling and script messages receiving in one WebViewRenderer in Xamarin IOs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Now I have code for web view renderer like:

```
 public sealed class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<WebView, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler
    {
        private const string ScriptMessageHandlerName = "native";
        private WKUserContentController userController;
        private WKWebView m_NativeView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var visualWebView = (ImWebView)Element;

            if (Control == null && e.NewElement != null)
            {

                this.userController = new WKUserContentController();
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration
                {
                    UserContentController = this.userController
                };

                this.userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, ScriptMessageHandlerName);

                m_NativeView = new WKWebView(this.Frame, config) { WeakNavigationDelegate = new ImNavigationDelegate()};


                SetNativeControl(m_NativeView);
    }

        public void DidReceiveScriptMessage(WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
        {
        ...
        }
}
```

This class allows me to receive messages from JS. But now I want to receive message that page loading is failed. I've found the only way to do so - use  `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.WebViewRenderer` as base class for my renderer and use

```
public sealed class MyWebViewRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.WebViewRenderer
 {

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var visualWebView = (ImWebView)Element;

            if (this.ViewController == null && e.NewElement != null)
            {
                base.Delegate = new CustomNavigationDelegate() { Control = visualWebView };
        }

            ...
     }



    public class CustomNavigationDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate
    {
        public ImWebView Control { get; set; }

        public override void LoadFailed(UIWebView webView, NSError error)
        {
          ...
        }
    }
 }
```

Load failing capture is working well, but with this code I couldn't get messages from JS. 
Is there any way to get both LoadFailed event and messages from JS code in one class?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to continue using the Renderer inheriting from `WKWebView`. We can use `DidFailNavigation` virtual method in `WKNavigationDelegate` to get callbacks when there is an error while Navigating. You can use it like below

```
public sealed class MyWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<WebView, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler
{
    private const string ScriptMessageHandlerName = "native";
    private WKUserContentController userController;
    private WKWebView m_NativeView;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var visualWebView = (ImWebView)Element;

        if (Control == null && e.NewElement != null)
        {

            this.userController = new WKUserContentController();
            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration
            {
                UserContentController = this.userController
            };

            this.userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, ScriptMessageHandlerName);

            m_NativeView = new WKWebView(this.Frame, config) { WeakNavigationDelegate = new NavigationDelegate()};


            SetNativeControl(m_NativeView);
        }
    }

        public void DidReceiveScriptMessage(WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
        {

        }
}
public class NavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{

    public override void DidFailNavigation( WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error )
    {
        // If navigation fails, this gets called
    }
}
```